# Python - having trouble selecting single value from json data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the following code from which I want to select a singular piece of data from the JSON.

I have the following code from which I want to select a singular piece of data from the JSON.

```
    j = {
    "data": [
        {
            "astronomicalDawn": "2023-01-16T04:58:21+00:00",
            "astronomicalDusk": "2023-01-16T17:00:31+00:00",
            "civilDawn": "2023-01-16T06:38:18+00:00",
            "civilDusk": "2023-01-16T15:20:34+00:00",
            "moonFraction": 0.36248449454701365,
            "moonPhase": {
                "closest": {
                    "text": "Third quarter",
                    "time": "2023-01-14T22:34:00+00:00",
                    "value": 0.75
                },
                "current": {
                    "text": "Waning crescent",
                    "time": "2023-01-16T06:00:00+00:00",
                    "value": 0.7943440617174506
                }
            },
            "moonrise": "2023-01-16T01:01:55+00:00",
            "moonset": "2023-01-16T09:53:57+00:00",
            "nauticalDawn": "2023-01-16T05:46:36+00:00",
            "nauticalDusk": "2023-01-16T16:12:16+00:00",
            "sunrise": "2023-01-16T07:28:07+00:00",
            "sunset": "2023-01-16T14:30:45+00:00",
            "time": "2023-01-16T06:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "astronomicalDawn": "2023-01-17T04:57:26+00:00",
            "astronomicalDusk": "2023-01-17T17:02:07+00:00",
            "civilDawn": "2023-01-17T06:37:07+00:00",
            "civilDusk": "2023-01-17T15:22:26+00:00",
            "moonFraction": 0.26001046334874545,
            "moonPhase": {
                "closest": {
                    "text": "Third quarter",
                    "time": "2023-01-14T21:31:00+00:00",
                    "value": 0.75
                },
                "current": {
                    "text": "Waning crescent",
                    "time": "2023-01-17T06:00:00+00:00",
                    "value": 0.8296778757434323
                }
            },
            "moonrise": "2023-01-17T02:38:30+00:00",
            "moonset": "2023-01-17T10:01:03+00:00",
            "nauticalDawn": "2023-01-17T05:45:35+00:00",
            "nauticalDusk": "2023-01-17T16:13:58+00:00",
            "sunrise": "2023-01-17T07:26:40+00:00",
            "sunset": "2023-01-17T14:32:54+00:00",
            "time": "2023-01-17T06:00:00+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "cost": 1,
        "dailyQuota": 10,
        "lat": 58.7984,
        "lng": 17.8081,
        "requestCount": 1,
        "start": "2023-01-16 06:00"
    }
}

print(j['data']['moonPhase'])
```

Which gives me this error;

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

That error is in regard to the very last line of the code. But changing the very very last line to `print(j['data'])` works.

What am I doing wrong - I am trying to select `moonPhase` data. It turns me on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print(j['data'][0]['moonPhase'])
```

or

```
print(j['data'][1]['moonPhase'])
```

Explanation: The `data` property of the json object contains a list.  There are two items in the list (item 0 and item 1).  You must first select an item using `[0]` or `[1]` before selecting the `moonPhase` property of one of the objects in the list.

edit: If you want to select only items where the moonPhase is in the future try:

```
print([
    item['moonPhase']
    for item in j['data']
    if (
        datetime.fromisoformat(
            item['moonPhase']['current']['time']
        ).timestamp() > 
        datetime.now().timestamp()
    )
])
```

output

```
[{'closest': {'text': 'Third quarter', 'time': '2023-01-14T21:31:00+00:00', 'value': 0.75}, 'current': {'text': 'Waning crescent', 'time': '2023-01-17T06:00:00+00:00', 'value': 0.8296778757434323}}]
```

Comment: Works. Why? This also works `j['data'][0]['moonPhase']['current'])`.

Comment: I see - there is two results. One for 1.16 and one for 1.17, Starts at astronomicaldawn. So i should do a for loop to make it dynamic / do work for each item. Thanks. I'll accept you answer, but I think a for loop is best. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example of using a list comprehension to compare the moonPhase datetimes against the current datetime.